# How to contact again someone who did not reply to my previous mail?

Tags: formality, email

It's a little bit awkward but I would like to know how I could contact again someone who didn't reply yet to my email  ? It's been almost 2 month since I sent some questions in Japanese to a Tokyo Museum Curator (who previously said to me 「ご質問ください」!), and once the questions asked (about Art History, nothing personal), I got no answer at all ! I'm worrying a lot, and I hope my questions didn't bother her... Are there any formal sentences to, first, apologize for contacting her again, and then to apologize if my questions did bother her ? (And If yes, that I'm deeply sorry if I said something wrong etc.)

Thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: (Partly) related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11642/9831